# AWS RDS SQL Server : export large data to CSV file from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, sqlbulkcopy

Migrating from a hosted SQL Server to AWS RDS which is a managed service (SaaS), we couldn't enable `xp_cmdshell`.

Our java app currently use a stored procedure that use `xp_cmdshell` to execute BCP.exe (*Bulk Copy Program is a command-line tool used to import or export data against a Microsoft SQL Server*) to export large data to CSV files.

And as `xp_cmdshell` cannot be enabled on RDS, we cannot use it to execute BCP.
Stored procedure code:

```
declare @bcp_header varchar(8000)
declare @bcp varchar(8000)
declare @bcpCopy varchar(8000)
declare @deleteFile varchar(300)

select @bcp_header = 'BCP "' + @header_select + '" queryout ' + @pathAndFileName +'.csv  -c -C 1252 -t; -T '
select @bcp = 'BCP "' + @sql_export + '" queryout  '+ @pathAndFileName +'_data.csv -c -C 1252 -t; -T '
select @bcpCopy = 'TYPE  '+ @pathAndFileName +'_data.csv >> '+ @pathAndFileName +'.csv'
select @deleteFile = 'DEL '+@pathAndFileName +'_data.csv'

exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcp_header
exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcp
exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCopy 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @deleteFile
```

Can we use a T-SQL command to export the query result to a CSV file and host it on S3 ?

Comment: If this is a one-off requirement, you could use SQL Server Management Studio. Run your  SELECT query, then right-click somewhere in the resultset and choose Save Results As....  You can save it as a well-formed CSV file.

Comment: @O.Jones yes but it's not a one-off requirement. I'm thinking about developping an SSIS package..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is use `BCP.exe` inside an SSIS package using the SQL Server that the SSIS instance uses.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we use a T-SQL command to export the query result to a CSV file and host it on S3 ?

Nope. There are TSQL alternatives to the BCP command, but ONLY for IMPORT.

Your best bet is to write a program that returns the data from SQL via some sort of SELECT statement and writes out the file yourself - bascailly a homebrewn replacement to BCP.

There is nothing out of the box that can act as a BCP replacement as all non BCP bulk functionality is either for programmatic use OR import only.